# How to upload a binary file (PDF) to Azure using File Services

Tags: azure, file, service, binary

I'm trying to upload a binary file (PDF or Word) to Azure using the Services from C#. I'm restricted to using the REST API's and therefore I cannot use the SDK.

I've managed to create the file but which REST API should I use to upload the content. As far as I can see the PUT RANGE is only for text (not for binary content).
Which File Services REST API should i use? Or is the File Services API not meant for this and should i use the Blob API?

Best regards,
Michel

```cs
                string endpoint_putrange = "https://" + ssStorageAccount + ".file.core.windows.net/" + ssShareNaam + "/" + ssBestandsNaam + "?comp=range";
                Uri _endpoint_putrange = new Uri(endpoint_putrange);
                HttpRequestMessage _requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, _endpoint_putrange);

                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(20000 * 10000); // 20sec in ticks
                httpClient.BaseAddress = _endpoint_putrange;

                string RequestDateString = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                // First set the header and construct the canonicalHeader string. See 
                // These must be in alpabetical order !!!!
                string canonicalHeaders = string.Empty;
                canonicalHeaders += setHeader(httpClient, "Content-Length", ssBestandsBinary.Length.ToString());
                canonicalHeaders += setHeader(httpClient, "x-ms-date", RequestDateString);
                canonicalHeaders += setHeader(httpClient, "x-ms-range", "bytes=0-"); // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/specifying-the-range-header-for-file-service-operations
                canonicalHeaders += setHeader(httpClient, "x-ms-version", "2020-04-08");  // https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/rest/api/storageservices/versioning-for-the-azure-storage-services
                canonicalHeaders += setHeader(httpClient, "x-ms-write", "Update");

                // Construct the canonicalResource string
                string canonicalResource = "/" + ssStorageAccount + "/" + ssShareNaam + "/" + ssBestandsNaam;

                // Construct the string to Sign
                string stingToSign = "PUT\n" + /*HTTP Verb*/
                "\n" +    /*Content-Encoding*/
                "\n" +    /*Content-Language*/
                ssBestandsBinary.Length.ToString() + "\n" +    /*Content-Length (empty string when zero)*/
                "\n" +    /*Content-MD5*/
                "\n" +    /*Content-Type*/
                "\n" +    /*Date*/
                "\n" +    /*If-Modified-Since */
                "\n" +    /*If-Match*/
                "\n" +    /*If-None-Match*/
                "\n" +    /*If-Unmodified-Since*/
                "bytes=0-" + "\n" +    /*Range*/
                canonicalHeaders +    /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
                canonicalResource;    /*CanonicalizedResource*/

                // Sign it
                HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256();
                byte[] dataToHmac = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stingToSign);
                string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));

                // Add the authorization header
                string authorizationHeader = ssStorageAccount + ":" + signature;
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("SharedKey", authorizationHeader);

                // How to specify the binary content of the _requestmessage/httpClient
                /// ?????????????????????????

                // Do the (synchronous) call and collect the response
                HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = httpClient.SendAsync(_requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

..... etc etc
```

Comment: `As far as I can see the PUT RANGE is only for text (not for binary content)` - This is not correct. You can use Put Range operation to upload the binary content as well. Please edit your question and provide more details as to how you're implementing the REST API.

Comment: @GauravMantri, Thanks for your answer. Oke great, then where I got stuck is where to put the binary content and how to encode it. Should I just put the binary content in the request body? How should this be encode? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code that you have written so far?

Comment: I've put the code so far in the original question

Answer (score 0):

Please try by setting the [`Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.content?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Http_HttpRequestMessage_Content) property of your `_requestMessage`. I am assuming that variable `ssBestandsBinary` is a byte array so you can set the `Content` property as [`ByteArrayContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.bytearraycontent?view=net-5.0).

Your code could be something like (not tested though):

```
_requestMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ssBestandsBinary);
HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = httpClient.SendAsync(_requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri, it works perfectly. Thanks.